# C++ snprintf "cannot pass objects of non-POD type"

Tags: c++, printf

I am trying to write a program that has a config and key file. The config file reads what ever is inputted into the key file, parses and executes the key values as needed.

I am getting an error: warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type ‘struct std::string’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime.

I am receiving the error on this line:

```
snprintf(command, 256, "tar -xvzf %s %s", destination, source);
system(command);
```

More of the code to try and better explain:

```
std::string source = cfg.getValueOfKey<std::string>("source");
std::string destination = cfg.getValueOfKey<std::string>("destination");
int duration = cfg.getValueOfKey<int>("duration");
int count, placeHolder, placeHolderAdvanced;
count = 1;
char command[256];

snprintf(command, 256, "tar -xvzf %s %s", destination, source);
system(command);

//Creates folder 1.
snprintf(command, 256, "mkdir %i", count);
system(command);

//Removes the last folder in the group.
snprintf(command, 256, "rm -rf %i", duration);
system(command);
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong, or where I should be looking?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`snprintf` knows nothing about `std::string`. In this case, it expects null-terminated C strings, that is, pointers to `char` which are the beginning of a sequence of characters that ends in a null character. You can obtain the underlying null terminated string held by a `std::string` object via its `c_str()` method:

```
snprintf(command, 256, "tar -xvzf %s %s", destination.c_str(), source.c_str());
```

Comment: This compiles and runs just fine for most of what i have been doing. But when I have destination = /path/to/somewhere and source = /path/from/somewhere. I get a couple of errors: tar (child) /path/from/somewhere: Cannot read: is a directory. tar (child) At beginning of tape, quitting now. tar (child): Error is not recoverable, exiting now.

Answer (score 5):

Use `c_str()` member function.

```
snprintf(command, 256, "tar -xvzf %s %s", destination.c_str(), source.c_str());
```

This will return a pointer to an array that contains a C-string representing the current value of the string object.

Answer (score 1):

Come on ! We are in the 21 century, go back to the top of the wave:

```
#include <sstream>
...
stringstream command;
command << "tar -xvzf " << destination << " " << source;
```